# Java string split with regular experssions

Tags: java, regex, string

I am far from mastering regular expressions but I would like to split a string on first and last underscore e.g.
split the string on first and last underscore with regular expression

```
"hello_5_9_2018_world" 

to

"hello"
"5_9_2018"
"world"
```

I can split it on the last underscore with

```
String[] splitArray = subjectString.split("_(?=[^_]*$)");
```

but I am not able to figure out how to split on first underscore.

Could anyone show me how I can do this?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the other answers are actually nicer and better, if you *really* want to use split, this is the way to go:

```
"hello_5_9_2018_world".split("((?<=^[^_]*)_)|(_(?=[^_]*$))")

==> String[3] { "hello", "5_9_2018", "world" }
```

This is a combination of your lookahead pattern `(_(?=[^_]*$))` 

and the symmetrical look-behind pattern: `((?<=^[^_]*)_)`

(match the `_` preceeded by `^` (start of the string) and `[^_]*` (0..n non-underscore chars).

Comment: Thank you. I would like to write less code to achieve the result. This is what I need. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this without regex. You can achieve this by finding the first and last index of `_` and getting substrings based on them.

```
String s = "hello_5_9_2018_world";

int firstIndex = s.indexOf("_");
int lastIndex = s.lastIndexOf("_");

System.out.println(s.substring(0, firstIndex));
System.out.println(s.substring(firstIndex + 1, lastIndex));
System.out.println(s.substring(lastIndex + 1));
```

The above prints

```
hello
5_9_2018
world
```

*Note:*

If the string does not have two `_` you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

To safeguard against it, you can check if the extracted indices are valid.

- If `firstIndex` == `lastIndex` == `-1` then it means the string does
  not have any underscores.
- If `firstIndex` == `lastIndex` then the string has just one underscore.

Answer (score 1):

**Regular Expression**

```
(?<first>[^_]+)_(?<middle>.+)+_(?<last>[^_]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IpIrMq/2)

**Java Code**

```
final String str = "hello_5_9_2018_world";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<first>[^_]+)_(?<middle>.+)+_(?<last>[^_]+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if(matcher.matches()) {
    String first = matcher.group("first");
    String middle = matcher.group("middle");
    String last = matcher.group("last");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have always three parts as above, you can use

```
([^_]*)_(.*)_(^_)*
```

and get the single elements as groups.

Answer (score 1):

I see that a lot of guys provided their solution, but I have another regex pattern for your question

You can achieve your goal with this pattern:

```
"([a-zA-Z]+)_(.*)_([a-zA-Z]+)"
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
    String subjectString= "hello_5_9_2018_world";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)_(.*)_([a-zA-Z]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(subjectString);
    if(matcher.matches()){
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    }
```

It outputs:

> hello
>
> 5_9_2018
>
> world